# How do I stop Teamviewer from remembering my email on the Computers & Contacts window?‏

Tags: teamviewer

Once I log in with the program, it will remember it forever. I'm trying to find a way I can disable this, but I can't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as it was a shared PC. I removed it by doing this.
Open the registry editor (regedit) from the run or the search menu from start.
Locate hkey_current_user\software\teamviewer\version8 | (BuddyloginName) delete the value here.